# How to know when AVAudioRecorder stop by saving audio to file successfully?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

Record something to the specified file by

```
[[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:_fileURL settings:settings error:&_error];
```

Need to play the recorded file immediately once stop the recorder and save file successfully.

Question is how to when is okay to read the file and playback it. Which delegate api could be used ?

Answer (score 1):

set the delegate of your `AVAudioRecorder` instance

```
AVAudioRecorder* test = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:_fileURL settings:settings error:&_error];
```

then implement

```
- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag 
{
    // play the recorded audio here
    if (flag)
    {
        NSError* error;
        AVAudioPlayer* player = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[recorder url] error:&error] autorelease];
        if (!error)
        {
            [player play];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag 
{
    // Play the audio
}
```